# Damage ordering with numeric key and wording key in object at the same time

Tags: javascript

Consider the following.

```
var options = {'All':'All'}
options['123'] = '123';
options['456'] = '456';
console.log(options);
```

The output of the above is `Object {123: "123", 456: "456", All: "All"}`, however, that is not what I want, I want to keep it's order and output as `Object {All: "All", 123: "123", 456: "456"}`

Why the ordering is damaged and how to avoid it?

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cgbxbdqb/)

Comment: object's keys have, actually no order. ususally the initial order is created by the creation.

Comment: Check again. It is in good order, as you want: https://jsfiddle.net/cgbxbdqb/1/ When you expand the object, you can see the order is right.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order